# Compilation errors with android.widget.MediaController

Tags: android, intellij-idea, mediacontroller

I'm trying to customize the MediaController. While doing so, I've stumbled upon a problem. Both my slightly modified version and the unmodified source of MediaController won't compile with intelliJ IDEA. When compiling the unmodified source code I get these errors:

```
mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);
```

Gives the error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol : variable PolicyManager
location: class android.widget.MediaController
```

Next error:

```
if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && event.isDown() && (
            keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK ||
                    keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE ||
                    keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE))
```

Gives the error:

```
Cannot find symbol
symbol : method isDown()
location: android.view.KeyEvent
```

My modified code also gives the above errors but also two more:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
);
```

Gives the error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol : variable LayoutParams
location: class android.widget.FrameLAyout
```

Next error:

```
addView(v, frameParams);
```

Gives the error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol : variable frameParams
location: class ........
```

I would be most thankful for any help.

I got the source code from GrepCode, http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/MediaController.java/?v=source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaController` requires access to classes and methods that are not part of the Android SDK, and therefore cannot be built as part of a regular SDK application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would it be possible to import them from somewhere else? If possible, from where?

Comment: @AlbinSäpoMattsson: `MediaController` as it stands can only be built as part of a full framework build, by downloading the whole OS and compiling it all. You are welcome to build your own media controller that does not have these limitations.