# cannot find symbol method setMediaController(MediaController)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, mediacontroller

I don't know what's wrong. But I get an error saying

> "Error:(62, 29) error: cannot find symbol method
>   setMediaController(MediaController)"

I'm trying to use videoview in recyclerview to play all the videos.
Instead of videoview I have used "FullScreenVideoView" library.

Please help me out.

Accident.java

```
package com.example.location.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.location.ImageUploadInfo;
import com.example.location.R;
import com.github.rtoshiro.view.video.FullscreenVideoView;

import java.util.List;

public class Accident extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Accident.ViewHolder>
{
    private MediaController mediaController;
    private Context context;
    private List<ImageUploadInfo> videoUploadInfoList;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        FullscreenVideoView videoview;
        public TextView imageNameTextView, TimeDate;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            videoview = (FullscreenVideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.videoa);
            imageNameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.VideoNameTextViewa);
            TimeDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.videotimea);
        }
    }

    public Accident(Context context, List<ImageUploadInfo> mainVideoUploadInfoList) {
        this.context = context;
        mediaController=new MediaController(context);
        this.videoUploadInfoList = mainVideoUploadInfoList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Accident.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleraccident, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new Accident.ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }
    public static int getScreenWidth(Context c) {
        int screenWidth = 0; // this is part of the class not the method
        if (screenWidth == 0) {
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            screenWidth = size.x;
        }

        return screenWidth;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final  ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try
        {
            holder.videoview.setMediaController(mediaController);
            ImageUploadInfo video=videoUploadInfoList.get(position);
            holder.imageNameTextView.setText(video.getImageDescription());
            holder.TimeDate.setText(video.getTimeDate());
            holder.videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video.getImageURL()));
            holder.videoview.getLayoutParams().height = getScreenWidth(context) * 9 /16;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.videoview.requestFocus();
        holder.videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                holder.videoview.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775232/compilation-errors-with-android-widget-mediacontroller

Comment: no help from that :(

Comment: solved the error. I was using fullscreenvieoview not videoview and setmediacontroller is method of videoview. :))

Comment: Post as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with `setMediaController()` was in changing import of `VideoView` - I was importing not `android.widget.VideoView`.

Who will have this error - make sure you are importing right `VideoView`.